# Can't load stl into URDF using ROS2

Tags: ros2, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in ROS 1 i used,  
for load a STL in URDF xacro file

But apparently this does not work in ROS2, how do I load an STL file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381116/can%27t-load-stl-into-urdf-using-ros2/) by [rsc](https://answers.ros.org/users/75575/rsc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-26**:
If you observed an error or warning message, I would suggest to include it, verbatim, in your question text.

That might help others figure out *why* it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/373495/). Xacro in ROS2 does not seem to support the `package` tag. Try using `<mesh filename="file://$(robot_description)/meshes/base.stl"/>` instead.

---

Originally posted by [djchopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/74140/djchopp/) with karma: 328 on 2021-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2